# Presence endpoint returns Forbidden with application permissions

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, http-status-code-403

With help from a fellow stacker, I was able to make successful calls to thre MS graph api, at least users, but I have been wanting to get the teams status of a user using the Presence function.  I have not been able to get around the 403 Forbidden error.  I have read much of the prose MS has written on OAuth 2.0 and have tried sample apps, graph explorer, and tried Postman as well.

I have checked my app permissions in Azure portal and according to the display, Presence is *application* able, not just delegate:

[image]

As I can perform a User.Read.All it is confusing that I cannot call Presence without the error.  This is the basic function I got help in writing and it fails on the presence call:

```
static async Task MainAsync()
{

    var tenantId = "some giud";
    var clientId = "more guid";
    var clientSecret = "even more guid";
    try
    {
        string[] scopes = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

        //var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();

        //foreach (var user in users)
        //    Console.WriteLine(user.UserPrincipalName);

        var userid = await graphClient.Users["my.name@company.com"].Request().GetAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(userid.Id);

        var presence = await graphClient.Users["{user id}"].Presence.Request().GetAsync();

       // Console.WriteLine(presence)
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I scoured google and MS looking for examples and I found one from MS and this is the link to github:

```
git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-devicecodeflow-v2.git
```

It will ask to perform a login via a browser and code.  I got this code working and it does ask that I log in.  I had to alter my registered app to this setting:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz9IK.jpg

All this I did and I still get the 403 forbidden error.  I am wondering if anyone has a working set of code that calls Presence and can share either **what I am missing**, or is this only something done in teams.

Why they have it so restricted is beyond reason given I can get more interesting user data just calling users/{emails}

Comment: According to the MS documentation and using the tool https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer, the required permissions are : Presence.Read and Presence.ReadAll (no admin consent required in both cases). I suggest you try in this tool and via Postman too to determine if the permissions you chose are correct.

Comment: I was able to find my availability (presence) via another endpoint. Try this query: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/microsoft.graph.getPresencesByUserId` with a http body like `{ "ids": [ "<user_guid_here>" ] }`. Read this MSDN documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/cloudcommunications-getpresencesbyuserid?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: [This API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions) doesn't support `Application` permission. That's why you got 403 error. And this means that when we want to use this api, we can only let users sign in first and get their own presence information via this api...

Comment: @Rivo I did use it in graph explorer.  I thank you for the option, but when I tried it using a tenant, client id, secret auth I still get forbidden.  I am just going to accept that there is not a way to programmatically get the presence of a user from a back end process or web page without some interactive sign in; that does not fit the display I'm trying to create.  Again this seems strange this one function (or datam point) is so locked down compared to other functions.  Thank you all for your responses.  I would have liked to get this to work, but it was not required.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the scenario and get the present status of the user .

I got the similar error `forbidden` when I gave a client secret which is expired and does not have Presence.Read.All delegated permissions .I only had application permissions

[image]

Then I added `delegated permissions` and `user.read` permissions (also granted admin consent).

[image]

I could get the status successfully with below code and query through graph where it uses access token (as authorization header is mandatory parameter to be passed ).

> **Note:** Getting the presence requires users signed in.So while requesting On behalf of user, delegated permissions are must.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var presence = await graphClient.Users["c4xx3cf2axxxxa6df-d2xxxx391"].Presence
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

***Presence of some user with Id***
[image]

Current user’s presence:

[image]

Please make sure to go through all the required constraints to [Resolve Microsoft Graph authorization errors - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/resolve-auth-errors)

It requires `Presence.Read` or `Presence.Read.All` Delegated permissions to query the presence of the user .

**Reference** : [Get presence - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)